# Session Objects not Updating ASP.NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, session, session-state, session-variables

I set a session object at one juncture in my code:

```
Session("my_name") = "Dave"
```

Later in my code I give the user a chance to update this object:

```
Session("my_name") = TextBox1.Text
```

I reload my page and display a little hello statement like this:

```
Label1.Text = "Hello" & CStr(Session("my_name"))
```

The result is: "Hello Dave" no matter what I change Session("my_name") too.

EDIT: Here is the a full code-behind I wrote up to demonstrated:

```
Public Class WebForm1
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
    Response.ExpiresAbsolute = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1)
    If Page.IsPostBack = False Then
        Session("my_name") = "Dave"
    End If
    Label1.Text = CStr(Session("my_name"))
End Sub

Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Session("my_name") = TextBox1.Text
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: You will need to provide the full codebehind in order for anyone to determine where your problem is.

Comment: When you set a break point on Session("my_name") = Textbox1.Text does it update?

Comment: Is Session("my_name") = "Dave" in your Page_Load?

Comment: @Germ - It is, but within a If..Then Page.IsPostBack=False clause

Comment: @Jack When I drill down in the autos portion of the debugger to Session-->Container-->System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionStateContainer-->Item it says, "In order to evaluate an indexed property, the property must be qualified and the arguments must be explicitly supplied by the user. So I can't see what it sets it too?

Comment: @davemackey: I already told you the solution, but for the record, you can use the Quick Watch window of Visual Studio, and enter Session("my_name") into it to check its value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Page`'s `Load` event fires up **sooner** than the `Button`'s click event. Therefore, at the time it runs, the value of `Session("my_name")` is still "Dave".

If you'd like to set it up correctly, you should either put the `Label1.Text = CStr(Session("my_name"))` into the `PreRender` event handler of your page.

You cut put it into the `Button`'s `Click` event as well (after setting the session value, of course), but I guess that you want to use the session later for storing objects for less trivial purposes.

(I guess that you'd like to use the session for more advanced purposes later. After all, what would be the point of using session if you only want to change a label's text?)

Basically, here is what you want:

- The Page_Load sets Session("my_name") to "Dave" if it is not a postback
- The Button1_Click sets Session("my_name") to the textbox's text
- The Page_PreRender sets the label's text.

Here's what's happening with your current code:

- The Page_Load sets Session("my_name") to "Dave" if it is not a postback
- The Page_Load sets the label's text
- The Button1_Click sets Session("my_name") to the textbox's text

You can read more about the topic in here: [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

Comment: Venemo - Thanks for the answer. I think you are right about the Page Load firing earlier than the button click event...but I don't understand exactly what you mean when you say, "or into the button's Click event" in the latter part - isn't that what I am already doing and what you just said isn't occurring until after page_load?

Comment: No, I mean that you should set the Label's text in the Button's Click event. You are setting it in the Page_Load currently. But if you are using session for a less trivial case, I'd certainly recommend the PreRender event of the page. (I edited my post to clarify.)

Comment: Thanks for your help. This issue has plagued me...It appears to be cleared up now.

Answer (score 3):

The `Page.Load` runs before your `Button1_Click` - so you are setting the value of your textbox to whatever you have in session, and then a bit later taking the contents of that textbox (which you have already overwritten) and popping it back into session.

Comment: Ugg, too slow with my answer, well answered by @Venemo :)

Answer (score 3):

You're not setting your *Session variable* default properly.  Basically you're setting the session variable to 'Dave' on *every* page load that's not a postback.  That even includes callbacks and page reloads.

To set the Session default try...

```
if( String.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["my_name"]) )
{
    Session["my_name"] = "Dave";
}
```

Now you can use your session variable without testing if it's part of a Postback or Callback.

Answer (score 1):

here's what worked for me:

```
objectName objectInstance = Session["mySession"] as objectName; //offload
objectInstance.attributeToUpdate = true; //update
Session["mySession"] = objectInstance; //re-assign
```