# c# Counter requires 2 button clicks to update

Tags: c#, .net, events, dataset

I have a problem that has been bugging me all day.

In my code I have the following:

```
private int rowCount
    {
        get { return (int)ViewState["rowCount"]; }
        set { ViewState["rowCount"] = value; }
    }
```

and a button event

```
protected void addRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rowCount = rowCount + 1;
    }
```

Then on Page_Load I read that value and create controls accordingly.

I understand the button event fires AFTER the Page_Load fires so the value isn't updated until the next postback. Real nightmare.

Here's the entire code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string xmlValue = ""; //To read a value from a database
        if (xmlValue.Length > 0)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                DataSet ds = XMLToDataSet(xmlValue);
                Table dimensionsTable = DataSetToTable(ds);
                tablePanel.Controls.Add(dimensionsTable);

                DataTable dt = ds.Tables["Dimensions"];
                rowCount = dt.Rows.Count;
                colCount = dt.Columns.Count;
            }
            else
            {
                tablePanel.Controls.Add(DataSetToTable(DefaultDataSet(rowCount, colCount)));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                rowCount = 2;
                colCount = 4;
            }
            tablePanel.Controls.Add(DataSetToTable(DefaultDataSet(rowCount, colCount)));
        }
    }

    protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        resultsLabel.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(DataSetToStringXML(TableToDataSet((Table)tablePanel.Controls[0])));
    }
    protected void addColumn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        colCount = colCount + 1;
    }

    protected void addRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rowCount = rowCount + 1;
    }

    public DataSet TableToDataSet(Table table)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable("Dimensions");
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);

        //Add headers
        for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows[0].Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            DataColumn col = new DataColumn();
            TextBox headerTxtBox = (TextBox)table.Rows[0].Cells[i].Controls[0];

            col.ColumnName = headerTxtBox.Text;
            col.Caption = headerTxtBox.Text;
            dt.Columns.Add(col);
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DataRow valueRow = dt.NewRow();
            for (int x = 0; x < table.Rows[i].Cells.Count; x++)
            {
                TextBox valueTextBox = (TextBox)table.Rows[i].Cells[x].Controls[0];
                valueRow[x] = valueTextBox.Text;
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(valueRow);
        }

        return ds;
    }

    public Table DataSetToTable(DataSet ds)
    {
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables["Dimensions"];
        Table newTable = new Table();

        //Add headers
        TableRow headerRow = new TableRow();
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            TableCell headerCell = new TableCell();
            TextBox headerTxtBox = new TextBox();
            headerTxtBox.ID = "HeadersTxtBox" + i.ToString();
            headerTxtBox.Font.Bold = true;
            headerTxtBox.Text = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName;

            headerCell.Controls.Add(headerTxtBox);
            headerRow.Cells.Add(headerCell);
        }
        newTable.Rows.Add(headerRow);

        //Add value rows
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            TableRow valueRow = new TableRow();
            for (int x = 0; x < dt.Columns.Count; x++)
            {
                TableCell valueCell = new TableCell();
                TextBox valueTxtBox = new TextBox();
                valueTxtBox.ID = "ValueTxtBox" + i.ToString() + i + x + x.ToString();
                valueTxtBox.Text = dt.Rows[i][x].ToString();

                valueCell.Controls.Add(valueTxtBox);
                valueRow.Cells.Add(valueCell);
            }
            newTable.Rows.Add(valueRow);
        }

        return newTable;
    }

    public DataSet DefaultDataSet(int rows, int cols)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("Dimensions");
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);


        DataColumn nameCol = new DataColumn();
        nameCol.Caption = "Name";
        nameCol.ColumnName = "Name";
        nameCol.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
        dt.Columns.Add(nameCol);

        DataColumn widthCol = new DataColumn();
        widthCol.Caption = "Width";
        widthCol.ColumnName = "Width";
        widthCol.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
        dt.Columns.Add(widthCol);

        if (cols > 2)
        {
            DataColumn heightCol = new DataColumn();
            heightCol.Caption = "Height";
            heightCol.ColumnName = "Height";
            heightCol.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
            dt.Columns.Add(heightCol);
        }
        if (cols > 3)
        {
            DataColumn depthCol = new DataColumn();
            depthCol.Caption = "Depth";
            depthCol.ColumnName = "Depth";
            depthCol.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
            dt.Columns.Add(depthCol);
        }
        if (cols > 4)
        {
            int newColCount = cols - 4;
            for (int i = 0; i < newColCount; i++)
            {
                DataColumn newCol = new DataColumn();
                newCol.Caption = "New " + i.ToString();
                newCol.ColumnName = "New " + i.ToString();
                newCol.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
                dt.Columns.Add(newCol);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            DataRow newRow = dt.NewRow();
            newRow["Name"] = "Name " + i.ToString();
            newRow["Width"] = "Width " + i.ToString();
            if (cols > 2)
            {
                newRow["Height"] = "Height " + i.ToString();
            }
            if (cols > 3)
            {
                newRow["Depth"] = "Depth " + i.ToString();
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
        }
        return ds;
    }

    public DataSet XMLToDataSet(string xml)
    {
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(xml);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(sr);

        return ds;
    }

    public string DataSetToStringXML(DataSet ds)
    {
        XmlDocument _XMLDoc = new XmlDocument();
        _XMLDoc.LoadXml(ds.GetXml());

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        XmlTextWriter xw = new XmlTextWriter(sw);

        XmlDocument xml = _XMLDoc;
        xml.WriteTo(xw);
        return sw.ToString();
    }

    private int rowCount
    {
        get { return (int)ViewState["rowCount"]; }
        set { ViewState["rowCount"] = value; }
    }
    private int colCount
    {
        get { return (int)ViewState["colCount"]; }
        set { ViewState["colCount"] = value; }
    }
```

EDIT: Here's my .aspx as well in case you want to try it out in VS.

```
    <asp:Panel ID="tablePanel" runat="server" CssClass="table-panel" />
    <asp:Label ID="resultsLabel" runat="server" />
    <asp:LinkButton ID="submit" Text="submit" runat="server" onclick="submit_Click" />
    <asp:LinkButton ID="addColumn" Text="Add Column" runat="server" 
        onclick="addColumn_Click" />
    <asp:LinkButton ID="addRow" Text="Add Row" runat="server" onclick="addRow_Click" />
```

Thanks in advance,

Marko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I've solved the problem by following instructions in [this](http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2005/03/11/1886.aspx) post.

Here's my final code - feel free to use it if you ever need to create dynamic controls based on a counter.

Also I wouldn't mind feedback on the overall coding style, I always appreciate others' input.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string xmlValue = ""; //To read a value from a database
        if (xmlValue.Length > 0)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                DataSet ds = XMLToDataSet(xmlValue);
                Table dimensionsTable = DataSetToTable(ds);
                tablePanel.Controls.Add(dimensionsTable);

                DataTable dt = ds.Tables["Dimensions"];
                rowCount = dt.Rows.Count;
                colCount = dt.Columns.Count;
            }
            else
            {
                tablePanel.Controls.Add(DataSetToTable(DefaultDataSet(rowCount, colCount)));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                rowCount = 2;
                colCount = 4;
            }
            else
            {
                if (GetPostBackControl(this.Page).ID == "addRow")
                {
                    rowCount = rowCount + 1;
                }
                else if (GetPostBackControl(this.Page).ID == "addColumn")
                {
                    colCount = colCount + 1;
                }
            }
            tablePanel.Controls.Add(DataSetToTable(DefaultDataSet(rowCount, colCount)));
        }
    }

    protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        resultsLabel.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(DataSetToStringXML(TableToDataSet((Table)tablePanel.Controls[0])));
    }
    protected void addColumn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void addRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public DataSet TableToDataSet(Table table)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable("Dimensions");
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);

        //Add headers
        for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows[0].Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            DataColumn col = new DataColumn();
            TextBox headerTxtBox = (TextBox)table.Rows[0].Cells[i].Controls[0];

            col.ColumnName = headerTxtBox.Text;
            col.Caption = headerTxtBox.Text;
            dt.Columns.Add(col);
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DataRow valueRow = dt.NewRow();
            for (int x = 0; x < table.Rows[i].Cells.Count; x++)
            {
                TextBox valueTextBox = (TextBox)table.Rows[i].Cells[x].Controls[0];
                valueRow[x] = valueTextBox.Text;
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(valueRow);
        }

        return ds;
    }

    public Table DataSetToTable(DataSet ds)
    {
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables["Dimensions"];
        Table newTable = new Table();

        //Add headers
        TableRow headerRow = new TableRow();
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            TableCell headerCell = new TableCell();
            TextBox headerTxtBox = new TextBox();
            headerTxtBox.ID = "HeadersTxtBox" + i.ToString();
            headerTxtBox.Font.Bold = true;
            headerTxtBox.Text = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName;

            headerCell.Controls.Add(headerTxtBox);
            headerRow.Cells.Add(headerCell);
        }
        newTable.Rows.Add(headerRow);

        //Add value rows
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            TableRow valueRow = new TableRow();
            for (int x = 0; x < dt.Columns.Count; x++)
            {
                TableCell valueCell = new TableCell();
                TextBox valueTxtBox = new TextBox();
                valueTxtBox.ID = "ValueTxtBox" + i.ToString() + i + x + x.ToString();
                valueTxtBox.Text = dt.Rows[i][x].ToString();

                valueCell.Controls.Add(valueTxtBox);
                valueRow.Cells.Add(valueCell);
            }
            newTable.Rows.Add(valueRow);
        }

        return newTable;
    }

    public DataSet DefaultDataSet(int rows, int cols)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("Dimensions");
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);


        DataColumn nameCol = new DataColumn();
        nameCol.Caption = "Name";
        nameCol.ColumnName = "Name";
        nameCol.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
        dt.Columns.Add(nameCol);

        DataColumn widthCol = new DataColumn();
        widthCol.Caption = "Width";
        widthCol.ColumnName = "Width";
        widthCol.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
        dt.Columns.Add(widthCol);

        if (cols > 2)
        {
            DataColumn heightCol = new DataColumn();
            heightCol.Caption = "Height";
            heightCol.ColumnName = "Height";
            heightCol.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
            dt.Columns.Add(heightCol);
        }
        if (cols > 3)
        {
            DataColumn depthCol = new DataColumn();
            depthCol.Caption = "Depth";
            depthCol.ColumnName = "Depth";
            depthCol.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
            dt.Columns.Add(depthCol);
        }
        if (cols > 4)
        {
            int newColCount = cols - 4;
            for (int i = 0; i < newColCount; i++)
            {
                DataColumn newCol = new DataColumn();
                newCol.Caption = "New " + i.ToString();
                newCol.ColumnName = "New " + i.ToString();
                newCol.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
                dt.Columns.Add(newCol);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            DataRow newRow = dt.NewRow();
            newRow["Name"] = "Name " + i.ToString();
            newRow["Width"] = "Width " + i.ToString();
            if (cols > 2)
            {
                newRow["Height"] = "Height " + i.ToString();
            }
            if (cols > 3)
            {
                newRow["Depth"] = "Depth " + i.ToString();
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
        }
        return ds;
    }

    public DataSet XMLToDataSet(string xml)
    {
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(xml);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(sr);

        return ds;
    }

    public string DataSetToStringXML(DataSet ds)
    {
        XmlDocument _XMLDoc = new XmlDocument();
        _XMLDoc.LoadXml(ds.GetXml());

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        XmlTextWriter xw = new XmlTextWriter(sw);

        XmlDocument xml = _XMLDoc;
        xml.WriteTo(xw);
        return sw.ToString();
    }

    private int rowCount
    {
        get { return (int)ViewState["rowCount"]; }
        set { ViewState["rowCount"] = value; }
    }
    private int colCount
    {
        get { return (int)ViewState["colCount"]; }
        set { ViewState["colCount"] = value; }
    }
    public static Control GetPostBackControl(Page page)
    {
        Control control = null;

        string ctrlname = page.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET");
        if (ctrlname != null && ctrlname != string.Empty)
        {
            control = page.FindControl(ctrlname);
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (string ctl in page.Request.Form)
            {
                Control c = page.FindControl(ctl);
                if (c is System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button)
                {
                    control = c;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return control;
    }
```

Comment: This GetPostBackControl is a clever idea.

Comment: Side note: in this context, the this instance is equal to the this.Page instance. Thus, you could write "if (!IsPostBack)" or "GetPostBackControl(this)". (Your page inherits from the Page class) ;)

Comment: Yeah thank god I found it as its solved all my problems! Thanks for your help, I've given you +1 for your effort. Marko

Answer (score 1):

Just as I recommended in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725279/session-objects-not-updating-asp-net/2725410#2725410), if you'd like some page logic to execute AFTER the buttons' `Click` event, put that code into the `Page_PreRender` instead.

You can read more about it here: [ASP.NET page life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

EDIT:

After examining your code more closely, I see that you add stuff and create new controls, which is not a good idea in the PreRender event. 
Instead, put the code into a separate method. In the Page_Load, check if it is a postback and handle the case when it isn't. 
In the buttons' click evnt, also add a call to that new method. (thus handling the IsPostback == true case)

Comment: Yes but then on my submitButton_click event the tablePanel is empty thus throwing an index out of range error.

Comment: It's a real catch 22. I moved the method that creates my controls right after the rowCount = rowCount + 1; and colCount = colCount + 1; code, but was experiencing the same issue when tried to submit the values.

Comment: Edited my answer, gave you a new idea.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I follow. I'm already checking if it's a postback and if it isn't, I'm just setting the default values to 2 and 4. In every other case the page should be recreating the controls with the updated values (rowCount and ColCount respectively). How will putting that in a method help?

Comment: The key is calling the method from the buttons' Click event.

Comment: The problem is that any time I create controls on the Button Click event, they're not available on the subsequent postback (i.e. submit). This is driving me completely nuts.

Comment: Yep I CAN create the controls everytime I assign + 1 to the colCount or rowCount. It works like a charm. But then when I click submit, poof! Paste the c#/ASP.NET code into VS, that's the whole working page and see if you can get it to work. I'm starting to grow white hairs. Gah.

Comment: I've solved the issue but thanks for your effort. I'll give you +1 once my rep goes up.

Answer (score 0):

move this code:

```
tablePanel.Controls.Add(DataSetToTable(DefaultDataSet(rowCount, colC....
```

To the prerender event to make the table bind to its data after the button click fired.

Comment: As you can see above I'm doing a set of checks before that code is executed. I've moved that entire chunk of code to the Page_PreRender event but the tablePanel is then empty on submit_click.

The error is:
Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
resultsLabel.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(DataSetToStringXML(TableToDataSet((Table)tablePanel.Controls[0])));

Comment: Any idea why the values aren't there on submit when the controls are created in PreRender, rather than Page_Load?